# $ is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a simple snake game in JS / jQuery, but that is no that important right now. I am getting this "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="500"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery usage is at the bottom of the code:

```
//defining the needed variables and classes
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const SNAKE_VEL = 10;

//direction enumeration calss
var direction = {
    UP: 0,
    RIGHT: 1,
    DOWN: 2,
    LEFT: 3
};

//the snake class
var snake = {
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    prevPosX: 0,
    prevPosY: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    direction: direction.RIGHT,

    move: function(){
        switch(snake.direction)
        {
            case direction.UP:
                if(snake.posY - SNAKE_VEL > 0)
                    snake.posY -= SNAKE_VEL;
                break;

            case direction.RIGHT:
                if(snake.posX + snake.width + SNAKE_VEL < canvas.clientWidth)
                    snake.posX += SNAKE_VEL;
                break;

            case direction.DOWN:
                if(snake.posY + snake.height + SNAKE_VEL < canvas.clientHeight)
                    snake.posY += SNAKE_VEL;
                break;

            case direction.LEFT:
                if(snake.posX - SNAKE_VEL > 0)
                    snake.posX -= SNAKE_VEL;
                break;
        }
    },

    draw: function(){
        context.fillStyle = "#97B";
        context.fillRect(snake.posX, snake.posY, snake.width, snake.height);
    }
};

//the food class
var food = {
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    prevPosX: 0,
    prevPosY: 0,
    width: 25,
    height: 25
};

context.fillStyle = "#458";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

//the main game loop
function gameLoop(){
    //set the background blue
    context.fillStyle = "#458";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

    //draw and move the snake
    snake.move();
    snake.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

//event handlers
//on key up event, see if the up,down,left or right buttons have been pressed
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    switch(event.which)
    {
        case 17:
            if(snake.direction != direction.DOWN)
                snake.direction = direction.UP;
            break;

        case 18:
            if(snake.direction != direction.LEFT)
                snake.direction = direction.RIGHT;
            break;

        case 19:
            if(snake.direction != direction.UP)
                snake.direction = direction.DOWN;
            break;

        case 20:
            if(snake.direction != direction.RIGHT)
                snake.direction = direction.LEFT;
            break;
    }
});

//request first frame
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

Comment: How are you loading the page?

Comment: Are you loading it from your machine's c: drive? AKA file protocol? That means that script path is being looked off your computer and not the internet.

Comment: Change `src="//ajax....` to `src="http://ajax...` -- the first approach only works if you're loading from an internet server, not from a local file.

Comment: The URL `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` is missing the scheme.

Comment: @DarkDust which is valid, just not when user runs it off file://

Comment: The scheme is omitted so that the page can handle http and https. That isn't the problem here.

Comment: @DarkDust - that's fine, and recommended by Google, although it needs to run from a real URL.

Comment: That makes it copy the scheme of the page it's being loaded from. If that URL is `file://...` it won't work.

Comment: Jsut a suggestion though ... Why not just use javascript for that specific instance too ..you haven't use jQuery  elsewhere

Comment: Well, I think it is working now I added http://, but it should work with // as well, shouldn't it? This is copied from the google website as it is.

Comment: Remember you can check your network activity in a situation like this to see if any HTTP requests failed.

Comment: @user3357969 **it will not work if you're loading the page from your local system (a `file://` URL).**

Comment: Run a local webserver! Apache or IIS. Easy to set up and you will not have these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `http:` in the beginning of your `src` attribute where you're trying to include jQuery. My guess is you're trying to load it locally on your machine, and not through a web server.

Answer (score 1):

The URL must be http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js, otherwise it will be looked in your local machine.

Comment: see numerous comments agreeing listed above.

Comment: The solution is probably correct, the _otherwise_ explanation is not.

Comment: My browser adds automatically file://, which brings me to my local home.

Comment: Your explanation is incomplete and therefore misleading. Perhaps you should explain when and why it will look at the local directory.

Comment: in fact it automatically prepends `file:` and makes the URL totally invalid, file not found error is thrown. Hence the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

1: Add external script as:

2: Regarding $ is undefiend. Replace $ with jQuery at all places.

Your provided code works in Chrome and Firefox.